# Union of submonoids of a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $E$ be a monoid. I know that the intersection of any 
family of submonoids of $E$ is again a submonoid of $E$. Under what conditions is the union of an arbitrary family of submonoids of $E$ a submonoid?

Comment: @MichaelKlyachman I don't see what guarantees that $ab\in A\cup B$ given that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a family of submonoids $\left\lbrace E_i\right\rbrace_i,\ E_i\subset E,$ I suppose that you need to ask for the condition that for $x\in E_1,\ y\in E_2; x,y\notin E_1\cap E_2 ,$ you have that $x*y\in E_1\cup E_2.$

Comment: Well, now I see that @Gae. S. answer the same in the comments.